# Pandas - add column with smoothed probability

Tags: python, pandas, probability-density

How do I create a new column that contains the density for each value from another column?

This gives the count, which is like taking values from a histogram:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['feature'])['feature'].transform('count')
```

What I would like is:

```
df['density'] = df.groupby(['feature'])['feature'].transform('density')
```

Which doesn't exist.  It would also be good to have a parameter for controlling the 'smoothness' of the density function.
[image: To illustrate, I would like values from the curve instead of the bar heights]

To illustrate, I would like values from the curve instead of the bar heights

Comment: By "density" do you mean to divide by the total number of elements? So `df['count'] / len(df)`?

Comment: I see what you mean, actually the smoothing part is critical.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)?

Comment: Yes if it is possible to get the plot values into a dataframe column next to their corresponding value.

Comment: you need to define parameters of the estimated distribution or the kernel